# Laravel How I can return view data with respone json (both in 1 time)?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $search_book = $request->id;

    $proc=DB::select(DB::raw("SELECT * FROM BOOKS WHERE BOOKID = '$Search_book'")

    if ($search_book!="") {
        return response()->json($proc);
        return view('status.status',[ 
          'proc' => $proc
    ]);
}
```

How to return 2 data

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by returning two things? It doesn't really make sense to return a json array of data and a blade view at the same time. So if you could clearify, maybe someone can give some advice.

Comment: Besides that, your query is unsafe the way you are executing it. **Never, ever** put variables into a raw query like this. Always use parameter binding or proper queries like `DB::table('books')->where('bookid', $search_book)->get()` or `DB::select(DB::raw('SELECT * FROM books WHERE bookid = ?'), [$search_book])`.

Comment: 1.Json get from Ajax event drop downlist send id to index controller
2. in controller have return view return data to view for loop data to table
Sorry i'm new use laravel ^^"

Answer (score 1):

To determine if a request is an ajax request, you can use the `ajax()` method on a `Request` object injected into the controll action:

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $results = DB::table('books')
        ->where('bookid', $request->id)
        ->get();

    if ($request->ajax()) {
        return response()->json($results);
    }

    return view('status.status', [
       'proc' => $results
    ]);
}
```

I went ahead and fixed the SQL injection vulnerability in your query for you by swapping the query for a proper one. It could still be improved by using a `Book` model instead of a plain database query, but it is fine this way as well.

---

The query from your comment can be simplified by replacing the `left join`. Simply take the sub query as base and `right join` it with `processspj`:

```
DB::table('processtrans as pt')
    ->leftJoin('processmaster as pm', 'pm.pcm_id', '=', 'pt.pct_pcm_id')
    ->rightJoin('processspj as ps', 'ps.pc_id', '=', 'pt.pct_pc_id')
    ->where('pt.pct_pc_id', $request->id)
    ->select([
        'ps.*',
        'pm.pcm_bname',
        'pt.created_at',
        'pt.updated_at',
        'pt.pct_id',
        'pt.pct_leadtime',
        'pt.pct_pcm_id',
        'pt.pct_pc_id',
        'pt.pct_planfinishdate',
        'pt.pct_startdate',
        'pt.pct_status',
    ])
    ->get();
```

Comment: This is my query but How i can convert to Laravel Query?

SELECT * FROM processspj  left join (select pcm_bname,processtrans.created_at,processtrans.updated_at,
        pct_id,pct_leadtime,pct_pcm_id,pct_pc_id,pct_planfinishdate,pct_startdate,pct_status
        from processtrans  left join processmaster on pcm_id = pct_pcm_id
        where pct_pcm_id  ='$search_book' ) as t on t.pct_pc_id = pc_id"));

Comment: And i think process is if dropdownlist change value 
1. Get data to textbox
2. Get detail to table 
Can return 2 response from 1 controller to same view ?

Comment: I don't get your last comment. Please try to rephrase it. Translating the query can be done as added in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just save the rendered view in a variable and do a json response:

```
public function index(Request $request) {
  $results = DB::table('books')
    ->where('bookid', $request->id)
    ->get();
if ($results) {
    $view = view('status.status', [
   'proc' => $results
        ])->render();

    return response()->json(['view'=> $view, 'proc' => '$results']);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#dl_books").change(function()
    {
        var getValue=$(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '{{route('status')}}',
            data: {id:getValue},

            success:function(data)
            {
                //Json for value textbox
                $("#txtbookname").text(data[0].pcm_bname);
             }

        });
    });
    });
```